# mgsmodbus of myarduinoprojects.com how to use it

Tags: ethernet, modbus, modbus-tcp

I'm trying to implement a  modbus tcp comunication between two arduino.

Following the two examples on myarduinoprojects.com, when I connect two controllino and load the program to the slave and master, it prints on the serial this [serial output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/McC9e.png), and a similar thing to the slave device.

Reading the code from the examples, I understood that if I send a number between 1 and 6 (but also 15 and 16) on the serial input, the program writes or reads different things from the slave. When I put on the serial input a number like 5, the ethernet port's LED blinks and I think that it means that some data pass between the controllino, but in the slave nothing happens.

How can I modify this program to send or receive boolean data (coils)? And if there are other libraries or programs that I can use, can someone tell me?